# UIScrollView is not scrolling in Xcode 5

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I created a subclass `MyCalender` of `UIView` and take `UIScrollView` in `MyCalender` class. And Use this `MyCalender` as subview of any other viewController. But the problem is that `UIScrollView` is not scrolling. I am using Xcode 5

MyCalender.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyCalender : UIView
{
    UIScrollView *scrollMonth;
}

@property(strong,nonatomic) UIScrollView *scrollMonth;

@end


MyCalender.M file ------ 


 #import "MyCalender.h"

@implementation MyCalender
@synthesize scrollMonth;


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        scrollMonth =[[UIScrollView alloc] init];
        [scrollMonth setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 66, 320, 220)];
        [scrollMonth setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 500)];
        [scrollMonth setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [scrollMonth setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

        [self addSubview:scrollMonth];

       //----------- ---------- -------- ---------


    }
    return self;
}
```

TestView class in which I used MyCalender class

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyCalender.h"


@interface testView : UIViewController
{

    MyCalender *viewCALENDER;
}
@property(strong,nonatomic) MyCalender *viewCALENDER;
@end
```

Testview.m

```
#import "testView.h"

@interface testView ()

@end

@implementation testView
@synthesize viewCALENDER;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    viewCALENDER=[[MyCalender alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, 320, 64)];
    [self.view addSubview:viewCALENDER];


}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: How do you know? What subviews does it have? What debugging have you done?

Comment: @Wain I add myCalender view on testView, I added more code so that you can understand easily

Comment: What happens if you set `scrollMonth.alwaysBounceVertical = YES;` ?

Comment: Scrollview is not scrolling after setting this property YES. :(

Comment: Set contentSize property

Comment: Kindly stop edit-vandalising this post. It is fine as it is now.

Comment: you have add the scrollMonth.delegate=self;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the looks of it, your scrollview is not visible in `viewCALENDAR`:

```
viewCALENDER=[[MyCalender alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, 320, 64)];
[scrollMonth setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 66, 320, 220)];
```

The container view (`viewCALENDAR`) has a 64px height, while your scrollview isplaced at y position 66.

To clarify on 'not visible' - the scroll view may be visible if `clipsToBounds==NO` for the container view, but in this case it will not be interactive.

Comment: Scrollview is visible but not scrolling